# CommandBar hides page content

Tags: xaml, windows-8, uwp

I am using Page.BottomAppBar to place a CommandBar at bottom of the page.
It hides the bottom content of the main view. How can the app bar "push" the content to show it all?  The content is a ScrollViewer.

UPDATE:

The Commandbar code is:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
     .... 
   </CommandBar>
 </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Then I have a grid, and the ScrollViewer is in one row of the grid. If I remove the app bar, everything works fine. The cursor is always visible, but when the app bar is visible, it overlays the content, like the images show.

The problem is that CommandBar overlays the page content. So, when InputPane appears,  Windows ensures that the input pane doesn't cover the focused element, but Windows puts the CommandBar over the content, hiding the focused control. I know that CommandBar overlays the page content by design, but there is a way to avoid it?

[image]

[image: With SIP]

Comment: Can you please show us your code? How can anyone debug this?

Comment: Yes, I need the CommandBar all time. I use -> large button to go to the next field (numeric SIP does not have it) or the Save button-

Comment: I have tested it. Sometimes it works well like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lrKGu.png). I'm looking forward for why this happened occasional. If you input something on SIP, it will work well. Did you still need to resolve this?

Comment: I am working on it. Now I am exploring using another approach, not <Page.BottomAppBar>. Now I use CommandBar in the Grid and I try to resize the window using InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing().